# C++ PImpl and Move Semantics

Tags: design, c++

Suppose I'm writing a C++ class with the PImpl idiom for the usual reasons of providing a stable ABI and/or reducing `#include` dependencies. I want the class to have value semantics: modifying a copy of the object has no visible effect on the original object. Assume doing a semantic copy (copying the implementation members) is not "fast" in some meaningful sense.

```
class Thing {
public:
    Thing();
    Thing(const Thing&);
    Thing(Thing&&);
    Thing& operator=(const Thing&);
    Thing& operator=(Thing&&);
    ~Thing();
    // Various accessor and mutator functions...
private:
    class Impl;
    std::unique_ptr<Impl> m_pimpl;
};
```

A tempting implementation of the move constructor would be

```
Thing::Thing(Thing&&) = default;
```

which is essentially the same as

```
Thing::Thing(Thing&& src) : m_pimpl(std::move(src.m_pimpl)) {}
```

But either of these leaves the moved-from `Thing` with a null `m_pimpl` member. Otherwise, I'd like to have a non-null `m_pimpl` as a class invariant. If any member function of `Thing` doesn't check for and deal with a null `m_pimpl`, that opens up accidental undefined behavior. [Herb Sutter's "Move, Simply" post](https://herbsutter.com/2020/02/17/move-simply/) makes a good argument that allowing that invariant violation for moved-from objects is bad design.

The options I can think of are:

1. A moved-from `Thing` is in a special restricted state. The only public member functions which can be called on it are the destructor, the assignment operators, and maybe some other functions with names like `reset` or `assign`. All other public member functions have a precondition that the object is not in this moved-from state. This is exactly what I read Sutter's article as warning against.
2. Don't implement move semantics for `Thing` at all. Every move is a full copy.
3. Allow `m_pimpl` to be null. Every public member function of `Thing` must check for this case before using `*m_pimpl`. Perhaps a default-initialized `Thing` also has null `m_pimpl`.
4. Make `m_pimpl` a `std::shared_ptr<Thing::Impl>` which is never null, and implement copy on write. Non-mutating functions can simply access `*m_pimpl`. Mutating member functions which use the existing state rather than replace it begin with a call to

   ```
    void Thing::copy_on_write() {
        if (m_pimpl.use_count() > 1)
            m_pimpl = std::make_shared<Impl>(*m_pimpl);
    }
   ```

All of these options have some benefits and drawbacks, it seems. What solutions, above or otherwise, work well and with a clean, maintainable design as a best practice for modern C++? What considerations are important when choosing how to implement the PImpl pattern?

[The Q&A ["Object lifetime invariants vs. move semantics"](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/310118/object-lifetime-invariants-vs-move-semantics) is a more general version of this question, but I'm specifically asking about the PImpl use case.]

Answer (score 2):

Option 2 is a good option if copying is a cheap operation anyway.

Option 3 is also a good option if having a NULL `m_pimpl` can be seen as a natural state of the object.

Besides those, there is also an option 5:

```
Thing::Thing(Thing&& src) : m_pimpl(std::make_unique<Impl>(std::move(*src.m_pimpl))) {}
```

Here, you create a new `unique_ptr` with a moved version of the `Impl` class. The Impl class can then decide for itself how to implement move semantics.